# Importar un maya file basado en la OCIO config

Tags: python, 3d

hola soy bastante nuevo en la progra, pero quería crear algunas herramientas para hacer mi vida más fácil, estoy tratando de importar una Shaderball diferente basada en la configuración de gestión de color que está activa.

me está dando este error:

**# Error: RuntimeError: file  line 26: colorManagementPrefs: Command does not support create mode. #**

no logro encontrar nada relacionado con el error solo errores que intentan importar la configuracion.

¿Supongo que mi if está mal o tengo que usar algo más en su lugar?

Gracias de antemano que tengan un gran día a todos

```
import maya.cmds as mc 

#shaderball folder path
sbp = "C:/Users/"user"/Desktop/";

#config  aces path
cfpACES = "C:/Users/"user"/Documents/Aces/aces_1.2/config.ocio";
 

#file type
ftype = "Ascii";


files = mc.getFileList(folder=sbp,filespec='*.%s' % ftype)

if (mc.colorManagementPrefs(configFilePath=True)) == cfpACES:
    mc.file("C:/Users/"user"/Desktop/Shaderball_ACES_Arnold.ma", i=True)

    
else:
    for f in files:
        mc.file("C:/Users/"user"/Desktop/Shaderball_LINEAR_Arnold.ma.ma"+ f, i=True)
```

Comment: hi, this site is in spanish, please translate your question

Comment: listo XD una disculpa intentaba publicarlo en la versión de ingles pero creo que me mando a la ES automáticamente